# Unable to parse json encoded values from php into JSON parse in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Hello I am trying to parse a data result from my database into my html view. I am not quite sure what is wrong with what I'm doing.

Here is my code:

```
function display($dbhandler){

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    foreach($dbhandler->query($sql) as $row){
        $data = array('id'=>$row['id'], 
                         'email'=> $row['email'], 
                         'name'=> $row['name']
                         );

        echo json_encode($data);        

    }

}
```

This will give me an output of:

> {"id":"1","email":"Email 1","name":"Name 1"}{"id":"2","email":"Email
>   2","name":"Name 2"}'

Now when I return and try to parse it using **$.parseJSON(result)** in jQuery.

```js
function display_list(){

  action='select';
  
  $.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url:"options.php",
   data:{ action : action },
   success: function(res){
    console.log(res)
    results = $.parseJSON(res);
    console.log(results);
   }
  });
 }
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 66
>       at Function.parse [as parseJSON] ()
>       at Object.success (actions.js:16)
>       at i (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
>       at A (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
>       at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)

Is there anything wrong with the data I am trying to pass? Any suggestions are welcome thanks.

Comment: the json returned is not valid, try posting that json on this website
http://jsonlint.com/
and see that the json you produce is not valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was within the server side of the script so I amended my code based on your suggestions and this is what I arrived with that works for me.

```
function display($dbhandler){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result = array();
    foreach($dbhandler->query($sql) as $row){
        $data = array('id'=>$row['id'], 
                         'email'=> $row['email'], 
                         'name'=> $row['name']
                         );

        array_push($result,$data);      

    }

    echo json_encode($result);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change following lines:

```
echo json_encode()($data);
```

to

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

and remove this line from the loop and put just after the loop ends. And make following changes:

```
success: function(res){
  var data = JSON.parse(res);
  alert(data[0].name); 
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand can you provide snippet so I can based on what was change?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function display($dbhandler){

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    foreach($dbhandler->query($sql) as $row){
        $data[] = array('id'=>$row['id'], 
                         'email'=> $row['email'], 
                         'name'=> $row['name']
                         );



    }
    echo json_encode($data);        
}
```

i just added the `[]` braces after your `$data`
which is equivalent to `array_push`
see [php arr_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Comment: still the same error i think the data is already an array when i use print_r it show that it is

Comment: what is the output json using the above changes? because what you have on top produces an invalid json in the first place, see my comment on your question

Comment: you are right there is something wrong with the way the data is being pass from the server side i figured what was wrong and it works now

Answer (score 0):

```
function display($dbhandler){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$data = array();
    foreach($dbhandler->query($sql) as $row){
        $data[] = array('id'=>$row['id'], 
                         'email'=> $row['email'], 
                         'name'=> $row['name']
                         );
    }
echo json_encode($data);       
        }
```

On jQuery function:

```
function display_list(){

        action='select';

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"options.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{ action : action },
            success: function(json){
                console.log(json)

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: The error is gone but it's not displaying any output

Comment: have you tried checking the response of Ajax call and checking the console bar as well. share the results please.

Comment: Yes I did it was completely blank when i tried it the other one was the error I said before although I did notice something different when I tried to push the array the first entry was duplicated which I find weird

Comment: use print_r to get the $row record, if it comes try putting print_r before json_encode and inspect the data.